# Is there a way to add an event listener on two separate divs and be able to know when the user clicked outside of one by itself?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am writing Javascript code that shows pictures on a category based on the ones the user clicked on but will show all categories when clicked outside the filtered pictures. Yet, I need the same code to work on separate divs independently, not the whole dom.

Attaching the event listener to the document works except, as you may have guessed, it doesn't work on two divs independently. When I attach it to a reference dom, let's day the dom id, it works but it doesn't know when the user clicked outside

```
        document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            //get an array of all the div with "column" class
            var imgElements = imgGrid.getElementsByClassName("column");
            var w, x; 
            var y, z;
            let targetElement = evt.target; // clicked element
            do {
                //itirate through all the divs we got the reference for
                for (var i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {

                    //check if we click on any of those divs
                    if (targetElement.className == imgElements[i].className) {

                        //we clicked on a div
                        //let's get the class name we want to filter by
                        w = imgElements[i].className;
                        x = w.split(' ');
                        console.log("You clicked on a: " + x[1]);

                        //we're not done //let's go itirate those divs once more
                        //but this time for everyone that don't have a class that
                        //matched our filter class we hide it, else we show it
                        for (var i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {
                            y = imgElements[i].className;
                            z = y.split(' ');
                            if (z[1] != x[1]) {
                                addClass(imgElements[i], "hidden");
                            } else {
                                removeClass(imgElements[i], "hidden");
                            }
                        }

                        return;
                    }
                }
                // Go up the DOM.
                targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
            } while (targetElement);

            console.log("You clicked outside");
//other useful things being done here
});
```

Instead of "document.addEventListener" I will say DomId.addEventlistner and expect it to know to when I clicked inside and outside of each dom reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can give DIVs that should be 'clickable' an unique class name. That way your logic doesn't have to know each 'inside' DIVs id.

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.className != "clickableDiv") {
    console.log("clicked outside");
  } else {
    var element = e.target.id;
    console.log(element + " clicked");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="clickableDiv">
  DIV1
</div>
<div id="container2" class="clickableDiv">
  DIV2
</div>
<div id="container3">
  I'm not clickable
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but it does not solve my problem. The problem in my case is I am writing some kind of producer code and I don't know how the consumer is going to use it. All I tell them is they have to provide me with a reference to an object to work on, in that case, a div id. Essentially, they might call my code multiple times to work on one or more divs

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now and edited my answer.